# The differentiability of convolutions

Tags: functional-analysis, distribution-theory, convolution

Yes, again, this type of question.
Similar ones [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/362779/differentiability-of-convolution/) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/7247/differentiability-of-convolutions/).

I come with another variant.
Let $f\in\mathcal{S}$, i.e. Schwartz function, and $g\in L^{p}(\mathbb{R}^d),p\in[1,\infty]$. The following should still hold
$$
\partial^\alpha(f*g) = (\partial^\alpha f)*g. 
$$

Basically we only need to prove the following case and the rest is simply by induction.

Here is my proof for $p\in[1,\infty)$, where are use the proposition 
$$D_i(f*g) = (D_if)*g,$$ provided $f,g\in\mathcal{S}$ and $D_i:=\frac
{\partial}{\partial x_i}$.

---

Taking arbitrarily fixed $x$,
\begin{align*}
|D_i(f*g)(x)| 
&=    \left|\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f*g(x+he_i)-f*g(x)}{h}\right|\\
&\leq \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}\left|\frac{f(x+he_i-y)-f(x-y)}{h}\right| |g(y)|\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&=   \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f_h(x-y)| |g(y)|\,\mathrm{d}y\\
&\leq \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\||f_h(x-\cdot)|\|_{q}\|g\|_p\\
&= \|D_i f\|_{q}\|g\|_p.
\end{align*}
By taking supremum, we have shown that $D_i(f*g)$ is bounded.
Hence $D_i(f*g)(x)$ is well-defined for all $x$.

Then, take a sequence $g_n\in\mathcal{S}$ such that $g_n\rightarrow g$ in $L_p$. Since
\begin{align*}
|D_i(f*g)-D_i(f*g_n)| 
&=    \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\left| \int_{\mathbb{R}^d}|f_h(x-y)| |g(y)-g_n(y)|\,\mathrm{d}y \right|\\
&\leq \lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\||f_h(x-\cdot)|\|_{q}\|g-g_n\|_p\\
&=    \|D_i f\|_{q}\|g-g_n\|_p \rightarrow \quad \text{as}\quad n\rightarrow 0.
\end{align*}

Besides, we know
$$D_i (f*g_n) = (D_i f)*g_n,\quad \forall n\in\mathbb{N}.$$
Hence,
\begin{align*}
|D_i(f*g)-(D_i f)*g|
&\leq |D_i(f*g)-(D_i f)*g - D_i (f*g_n) + (D_i f)*g_n|\\
&\leq |D_i(f*g)- D_i (f*g_n)| + |(D_i f)*g_n-(D_i f)*g|\\
&\leq |D_i(f*g)- D_i (f*g_n)| + \|(D_i f)\|_{q}\|g_n-g\|_{p}\rightarrow 0 \quad\text{as}\quad n\rightarrow \infty,
\end{align*}
where we applied Young's inequality in the last step.

Is it correct?
And how should I work on the case $p=\infty$.

Comment: The expression within the $||.||_q$ converges pointwise to $f'(x-y)$. And as you have an integrable majorant ($f$ and $f'$ decay faster than any polynomial), you can apply the dominated convergence theorem.

Comment: @Vobo Thanks for the comment. But we only know $g\in L^p$, how can I handle this?

Comment: I am not completely sure about the well-definedness. For instance, $\lim_{n \to \infty} |(-1)^n| \le 1$, hence the sequence is bounded, but the limit does not exist.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your answer is correct. Let me show you the case $p=\infty$. As above, it is well-defined. Let $p(x)=(1+||x||^2)^n$. Note that $1/p$ is integrable and $pf$ and $p(D^if)$ are (uniformly) bounded. Then
$$
\Big| D^i (f\ast g) (x) - (D^i f\ast g)(x)\Big| \leq ||g||_\infty \lim_{h\to 0} \int |f_h(x-y) - (D^i f)(x-y)| dy.
$$
As $f_h\to D^i f$ pointwise, you need to justify the dominated convergence theorem. This can be done by adding the factor $\frac{p(x-y)}{p(x-y)}$ to the integral: You still have 
$$
\lim_{h\to 0} |p(x-y) f_h(x-y) - p(x-y)(D^i f)(x-y)| = 0
$$
pointwise and this term is uniformly bounded. This bound times $1/p$ is an integrable majorant, so the use of Lebesgue is justified.

Comment: Thanks. I also figured out that we can use the property of Schwartz function to argue it.